# Sidebar is floating over the footer

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a sidebar (which sometime is longer than the content section). 

I've the demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/y9hp4evy/1/  
THe second case: http://jsfiddle.net/y9hp4evy/2/  (If I add a height to sidebar)

But when the sidebar content is longer, it goes over the footer. And some content is below the end of the sidebar section.

```
.container {
    width: 800px;
}

.right-pane {
    float: right;
    width: 300px;
}

.left-pane {
    margin-right: 320px;
    position: relative;
    min-width: 300px;
}
footer{
    background-color: #cdc;
}
```

What am I missing here? Can't find the right solution on the search results too.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It doesn't appear to be when I look at the jsFiddle

Comment: What do you see in the jsfiddle? Scroll down to the bottom to see the footer.

Comment: @cfly24: I just updated the question. Pleas check now.

Comment: u are missing clearfix

Comment: Also in second example u have height fixed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS float property unexpected behavior](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12450403/css-float-property-unexpected-behavior)

Comment: @Berendschot: Both questions are entirely different. I've gone through that answer as well. Please, do not just search for any question and say its' a duplicate question. Thanks.

Comment: @GoranJakovljevic: I tried all those before asking here. Please don't downvote before you go through the problem that I mentioned here. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In cases like this, make sure your sidebar is contained in the main content wrapper. ie:

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="article"></div>
  <div id="sidebar"></div>
</div>

<footer></footer>
```

You then make sure your CSS has a clearfix for the main 'container'. ie:

```
#container:after{
  content: "",
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
```

Here's your second JSfiddle edited: http://jsfiddle.net/y9hp4evy/3/ 
Note that I removed the height attribute for the sidebar. Never enforce height unless you are ready to handle overflow cases. Much better to use `min-height`

Comment: I tried this. But not working. Can you try this on the http://jsfiddle.net/y9hp4evy/1/

Comment: I edited my answer. Remove the sidebar height. Either have height and block overflow, or don't have height in case you aren't sure how long your content will be.

Comment: But when I go here; http://jsfiddle.net/y9hp4evy/2/   I see the sidebar floating over the footer.

Comment: Nope, the jsfiddle you've given has the same two problems I mentioned in my question. This time, some part of the content is below the sidebar. There's a huge space between the First paragraph and the second one.

Comment: That's because you're not aligning the content properly. Make sure you have fixed widths whenever you have floats. Let's say you have 100px container and your sidebar is 20px. Your other content should be <=80px to be able to fit next to each other. Also, remember to add `box-sizing:border-box;` to guarantee that you don't push the dimensions.

Comment: Can you please show it on the jsfiddle you created? I guess I already have  the right widths for floats.

Comment: @user1012181 Don't use stackoverflow to do all the work for you! Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/y9hp4evy/9/

Answer (score 0):

Here is the first one fixed:

```
.right-pane {
    float: right;
    width: 300px;
}
.left-pane {
    float:left;
    position: relative;
    width: 300px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6929kcc7/2/

Here is the second one:

(I removed height of sidebar)

http://jsfiddle.net/y9hp4evy/8/

Update:

http://jsfiddle.net/6929kcc7/3/

so use col-sm-4 and inside it add sidebar that has fixed width.

Comment: The sidebar width has to be: 300px and the content area has to be Flexible depending on the screensize. That's why I floated only the sidebar.

Comment: Why not use percentage? 

Is site full width or u have container of 800px ?

Comment: it's a responsive page. Sometimes the container size is 1070px, sometimes, it's 970px depending on the screensize. But always the sidebar has to be 230px and the content area width is flexible depending on the screensize.

Comment: Maybe split it with percentage, like nine and three, and make sidebar max-width:230px; So col-md-9 and col-md-3 for sidebar. U use bootstrap?

Comment: It shows Content width is 300px which is not flexible on different screens. :/

Comment: Content width is 66.66666667%, its fluid, container width should have max width like u said 970 or 1170 or whichever u chose.